# Update select list without refresh [PDO/PHP/AJAX]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I'm using bootstrap and i've created teo tabs that insert data into database, but the first tab have a selection list that loads data inserted using the form in the second tab.
The problem is that i can't fill the selection list in the first tab without refreshing the page.
I've tried inumerous solutions here in stackoverflow and googling but no one worked.

Here is the code of the form and php:

```
<form class='form-horizontal' role='form' action="index.php" method="post" id="nl_0" name="nl_0">
<div class='form-group'>
    <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='id_accomodation'>Tipo de Produto</label>
        <div class='col-md-2'>
            <select class='form-control' id='id_accomodation' name="id_accomodation" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                <?php
                try
                {
                    $db = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost dbname=blablabla user=postgres password=*****");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM taxes ORDER BY type");
                    $stmt->execute();

                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $options .= "<option>" . $row{type} . "</option>";
                    }
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    echo "Error:". $e->getMessage();
                }
                ?>
                    <?php echo $options;?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The only thing that doens't work is the auto update without refresh.
Any help i will be very thankfull!

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is `Ajax`

Comment: Yep, i already tried AJAX. If i had not tried i would not tag the post with the tag AJAX ¬¬

Comment: You want a php file that returns (i.e. echos or prints) nothing but the dropdown list not a whole html file. Then in your html file (or php file that is a whole html file) call that php file with ajax to just get that one component and stick it in a div

Comment: And what didnt work with Ajax?

Comment: i.e. don't make index.php call index.php via ajax, as that will just return a duplicate of the whole page...I imagine that's what you did since its what everyone does the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using ajax for every tab request and writing again my code.

Comment: Alex, could you share your code that fixed it? I'm having a very similar issue.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer! Will try to find the code and will post it here.