# Php how to load a div with a selected item from li

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i need help please.

I want if I select something from the list right next to a div updated with the data of the selected.

I have a ul and there is a foreach loop that lists all clients in a li. it should show me all the data on it right in the div and the problem is I do not know how I can load the variables of the selected only update the div and not the whole page

he shows me data on the right in the div but not that I have selected but the last in the list

```
<ul id="msgUl">
            <?php


            foreach($it as $a)
            {

            ?>

            <li class="thumbLi" id="<?= $a[3];?>">
                <div style="position: relative;">

                    <div id="tmbMsg">
                        <img id="thumbMsg" src="https://website.com/pics/<?= $a[2];?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="loFullMsg">
                        <a href="delete.php?delete=<?= $a[3];?>">
                            <button title="Delete" href="delete.php?delete=<?= $a[3];?>"></button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="nameMsg">
                        <div id="nameFullMsg">
                            <?= $a[0];?>
                        </div>
                        <div id="titelFullMsg">
                            <?= $a[1];?>
                        </div>
                        <div id="prevFullMsg">
                            <span id="listMsg">
                                <?= $a[4];?>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <?= $a[5];?> | <?= $a[6];?>
                            </span>           

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <?php

            }

            ?>
        </ul>
```

i marked the selected li here

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#msgUl li').click(function () {
        $('#msgUl li').removeClass('selectedMsg');
        $(this).addClass('selectedMsg');

    });
});
```

Everything works here the problem now is if i select a li how can i get the variables from the selected zu the other php that have to load the div without refreshing the page!

Thanks and regards grenz

Comment: hum i think you must use ajax to do that. For example jquery ajax() function, you can find a lot of tutorials online

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update select list without refresh \[PDO/PHP/AJAX\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709225/update-select-list-without-refresh-pdo-php-ajax)

Comment: but i dont get the value of the selected li i get the last in the list i dont know

Comment: update your answer with ajax code

Comment: In your comment you doesn't use ajax....

Comment: yes the load with div works now but with the wrong data

Comment: i wont the variables from the selected li but it gives me always the last one in the li

Comment: where do you get the selected li in your code? for example when you click on it?

Comment: @Sfili_81 with javascript if i clicked it changes to the class to selectedMsg code is in description

Comment: Have a read up on `.append`, `.insert`, `.load`, `.html`, `.text` etc there are many ways to update a div without refreshing, you just need to read the manual and do some tutorials as this is very basic stuff.  As no attempt has been made and there are too many ways to answer this question, I vote to close it as too broad

Comment: @Pete its not only this i can load the div without refreshing but i cant load it with the correct data from the selected li

Comment: I'm almost sure that you are messing JS with PHP.
Where is the data you want to show? Are you showing only the name from li and want to expand something when clicking on it? How the structure of $it PHP table looks?